# Hazelcast: Can I configure a Map per JVM?

Tags: java, hazelcast

Is there some option in Hazelcast to make the map cache values per node, and not replicate his state? I thought that this was the difference between `getMap()` and `getDistributedMap()` but it seems that both is replicated between nodes.

I have an application in a Weblogic cluster, my configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast>
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</property>
    </properties>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true">5107</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false" />
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <members>127.0.0.1:5701, 127.0.0.2:5702</members>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>
    <map name="default">
        <time-to-live-seconds>1800</time-to-live-seconds>
        <backup-count>0</backup-count>
        <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    </map>
</hazelcast>
```

In the logs I can see that both nodes are up

```
Members [2] {
        Member [127.0.0.1]:5107
        Member [127.0.0.1]:5108 this
}
```

When I call my method in the first node I can see that the cache is added

```
.Default (self-tuning)'] [] DEBUG b.c.l.c.c.i.e.c.h.AbstractHazelcastCacheInterceptor - Hazelcast instance HazelcastInstance{name='my-instance', node=Address[127.0.0.1]:5107}
2015-03-31 21:09:40.040 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [] DEBUG b.c.l.c.c.i.e.c.h.AbstractHazelcastCacheInterceptor - Cache map IMap{name='MY_APP.Cache.cacheName'}
2015-03-31 21:09:40.040 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [] DEBUG b.c.l.c.c.i.e.c.h.AbstractHazelcastCacheInterceptor - adding object in the cache with key 2342425
```

But in the second node I only see the cache name log, so it's using the already added cache...

```
.Default (self-tuning)'] [] DEBUG b.c.l.c.c.i.e.c.h.AbstractHazelcastCacheInterceptor - Hazelcast instance HazelcastInstance{name='my-instance', node=Address[127.0.0.1]:5108}
2015-03-31 21:09:40.040 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [] DEBUG b.c.l.c.c.i.e.c.h.AbstractHazelcastCacheInterceptor - Cache map IMap{name='MY_APP.Cache.cacheName'}
```

Am I missing some configuration? Is it possible to achieve with Hazelcast?

Comment: why would you want to use Hazelcast for this instead of a normal Java Map (or a Guava cache or something similar)?

Comment: The requirement is to be able to perform a distributed evict, but not share cache data.

Comment: so you want to be able to put stuff only locally but when you evict it should evict on all nodes? that doesn't sound like a very transparent solution. Don't think hazelcast supports that, guess you could easily implement it using hazelcast's `ITopic`, publishing eviction and having a listener on each node.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Yeah, I want to use network to perform operations only when this is really necessary. I will try ITopic, thanks!

Comment: @SérgioMichels tell me please how do you managed to configure slf4j to log in DEBUG mode? May you look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391834/hazelcast-programmatic-configuration-for-logging-in-debug-mode please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment a use case where:

- `put(key, value)` adds the tuple only locally
- `evict(key)` evicts it from all the maps

Isn't really that transparent and I doubt Hazelcast (or any popular in-memory grid) supports it out of the box but what you can do is implement a very simple `pub-sub` with Hazelcast. On each hazelcast node you start a topic listener:

```
ITopic<String> eviction = hazelcast.getTopic("evict");
eviction.addMessageListener(new EvictionListener());
```

Where `EvictionListener` would be something like:

```
public class EvictionListener implements MessageListener<String> {

   @Override
   public void onMessage(Message<String> message) {
      // Gets the local (per JVM) cache and evicts an entry from it
      Cache.getCache().evict(message.getMessageObject());
   }
}
```

And then you can implement your eviction method as:

```
public void evict(String key) {
    hazelcast.getTopic("evict").publish(key);
}
```

Something like this. Then you need to create a cache (as I mentioned a simple Java Map or a Guava cache) per JVM and use the evict method for eviction.

Comment: Thanks! I remembered that the hibernate integration creates a local cache. Probably will do an implementation based on that, combining with your tips.