# Hazelcast: programmatic configuration for logging in debug mode

Tags: java, logging, hazelcast

Trying to configure `slf4j` to log in DEBUG mode, but get only INFO logs. What am I doing wrong?

```
Config hazelcastConfig = new Config("HazelcastConfig");
hazelcastConfig.getProperties().put("hazelcast.logging.type", "sl4j");
hazelcastConfig.getProperties().put("slf4j.logger.com.hazelcast", "debug");
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try

```
Config hazelcastConfig = new Config();
hazelcastConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig);
```

Keep in mind that slf4j is just facade API for logger. You should use it with actual loggers, like log4j or logback. All required jars should be in a classapath s well. Here is a [tutorial of slf4j and logback](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/using-slf4j-with-logback-tutorial.html) 
Here is an example of `logback.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.hazelcast" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Thank you