# How can I configure Hazelcast logging

Tags: hazelcast

In my Spring config file I have Hazelcast configured

```
<!-- Hazelcast -->
<hz:hazelcast id="hazelcast">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:properties>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</hz:property>      
        </hz:properties>

        <hz:network port="$server{hazelcast.port}" port-auto-increment="false">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="$server{hazelcast.multicast.enabled}" />
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="$server{hazelcast.tcp-ip.enabled}">
                    <hz:member>appserver_1</hz:member>
                    <hz:member>appserver_2</hz:member>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>

        <hz:map name="aaaaaaaaaaa" />
        <hz:map name="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" />


        <hz:map name="clientSessions">
            <hz:entry-listeners>
                <hz:entry-listener implementation="clientSessionListener"/>
            </hz:entry-listeners>
        </hz:map>

    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

What I now want to do is change the logging level to see what Hazelcast is doing ?

How do i do this ?

---

Answer (unable to answer as yet !)

In the file log4j.xml

I added this:

```
<logger name="com.hazelcast">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

Comment: I already answered similar question regarding slf4j and Hazelcast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391834/hazelcast-programmatic-configuration-for-logging-in-debug-mode/30440457#30440457

Comment: Completely different mate !

Comment: your question (answer?) is incomplete. Do you use slf4j with log4j? or do you use log4j only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file log4j.xml

I added this:

```
<logger name="com.hazelcast">
  <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Thanks - couldn't edit this to get the code showing !